# Syncing database with google fusion table

Tags: coldfusion, google-fusion-tables

I am having troubles figuring out the google api.. I am trying to insert data into my fusion table via my coldfusion application..

```
<cfhttp  url="https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin"  method="post" charset="utf-8">
<cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="accountType" value="GOOGLE"></cfhttpparam>
<cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="Email" value="MYUSERNAME"></cfhttpparam>
<cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="Passwd" value="MY PASSWORD"></cfhttpparam>
<cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="accountType" value="GOOGLE"></cfhttpparam>
<cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="service" value="fusiontables"></cfhttpparam>
</cfhttp>
```

this comes back with

```
SID=DQAAALoAAAC5eSJUrVB_WVchS1plunfW2YPUTadHAxoEbE0xMcOzQxeTloc2RWWBjoJi4jKm6NIiFbGbV_IQ3vuY9bl-Z0RS64OFAy5aUY-Do_nX8DpPhVkEyBzDScJidi73G7ZqWmkdykkIGCBrr7MLa-eBMrXZvLJP0D21xJTjxRWyeM4xuEMQGhEbnWwBL9RnEByr5Rsgzx7dl9n4tsYQOvaGV3ZcMlT0CooS2__orwC12UH7eKCk-REKzbX5Z-bbu4EdLps LSID=DQAAALwAAABV7lz-YRh02pR7IlWkKidScbYTQArBWnaAJpAlZQ9rgtgmdQCSBuIZQQ21QDXZLORwTAyDi-34Mjs8SKvI7ronBSuniDW2SGipYoUhZDEjxwR55DQc1AaI3JgGPMc69YGAVv-_EMwXlS7elWO6lDW-G4PTR6Aqa0DO3y7Iig-L7g2b7zMFq32JIvjUj5rofcykF27T8sOuhd0Z4XTvgO-18Kp2z8o6EK_5qjZcHPmih0GB6LeSElBo2wjah1TM2u0 Auth=DQAAALwAAADYQbciaOLab2Aw_QghTO8hR0DPDOjoWZVKeJ-ApGwoUz7OgcqVtSHMUvRHHZoKys5ygjhm2FiHSh1CvW1SicOvajwRZSstvghtsCQl-y7LeT8TMkeCj5ZIqy8A05wg1YjCz3F3eDz9TImtlvGij7IOdWJ3Ae4NE8WQdC0Js5Laccebhgjj7Lk9FkRgG9c3yRyGhu7LmsRbtLjfv5jwGoozDuCcx6b79bECoR8qABkT-e5HgF7sWjYbLfz667OCeA0
```

Now I am trying to insert into my table... I am passing the auth value from above.. I can not find anywhere in the google docs what the authentication fields should be.. any help would be greatly appreciated..

```
<cfhttp url="https://www.google.com/fusiontables/api/query" method="post" charset="utf-8">
<cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="sql" value="INSERT INTO 423555 (id, outcode,lat,lng) VALUES ('1','W14',1231232,-123123);"/>
<cfhttpparam type="header" name="Authorization" value="Auth"></cfhttpparam>
<cfhttpparam type="header" name="token" value="#listtoarray(cfhttp.FileContent,"=")[4]#"></cfhttpparam>
</cfhttp>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The AUTH should be the auth token you received in google's response.

From [the docs](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/auth/overview.html#ClientLogin) you should make a header like:

```
Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=yourAuthToken
```

So, this would be

```
<cfhttpparam type="header" name="Authorization" value="GoogleLogin auth=#listtoarray(cfhttp.FileContent,"=")[4]#"></cfhttpparam>
```

This is assuming the #listtoarray(cfhttp.FileContent,"=")[4]# returns the value of the Auth property - I haven't counted it out to be sure.

I don't think, just glancing at the docs, the "token" header is needed.

But, #listtoarray(cfhttp.FileContent,"=")[4]# is a really fragile way of doing it.  If Google were to reorder their response or change it, your code wouldn't work any more.

I would look to a more robust way of parsing the response.  I would probably split the response on whitespace and turn it into a struct with the names as keys, then you could use something like

```
#response['auth']#
```

Comment: wow awesome it worked...you are a legend!!.. i think you're right about spliting in by whitespace.. ill give that a go.. thanks again..